# Listing multiple degrees on a resume

Tags: resume

I currently have 2 undergrad degrees, 2 technical diplomas and 2 masters degrees, all from different fields, and am looking to start a part-time PhD next year.

Is there a space efficient way to list all this on a resume, because currently even just listing the degree/diploma and the institution takes up over half a page?

Edit: Adding in current format:

> Bachelor of Computer Science (Software Engineering/Systems Security)
>    - University of XX 2007-2009
>    - Dean's Scholar

Comment: Just list them sequentially, newest to oldest.

Comment: This just sounds like a formatting issue: six items, each with field, institution and a date. I don't see any reason that that should take up over half a page.

Comment: I don't see any reason that should take up more than 12 lines (plus space to mention relevant thesis). Warning: some folks will look at that list and think "indecisive dilettante"  unless you have a good story for why you needed expertise in all those area.

Comment: @keshlam That depends on how different. Jumping from Philosophy to Civil Engineering is a big leap. Physics to Computer Science, not so much.

Comment: @HorusKol Hence why sorting them chronologically is important, so they can see the path you took to where you are now.

Comment: This question may be more suitable on [Academia SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @scaaahu I'm looking for feedback on how an industry will view it, not for how the academic community will view it. From what I understand they have very different views of things.

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by 2 undergrad degrees? From the same school? Both are computer science? One is software engineering and the other is Systems Security? Or actually, one is major and the other one is minor? Or double major?

Comment: @scaaahu I did a BCS majoring in software engineering and systems security at one university, then I went and did a BSc at another majoring in Chemistry and Physics with Honors. Following that I did a Masters of Professional Engineering with an electrical engineering focus, followed by an MBA. Both Masters were done part time, and my diploma's are in Human Resource Management and database system administration, also done part time.

Comment: Based on lurking on Academia.SE, subject-hopping can raise red flags if you plan an academic research career. If you plan a more applied/industrial Ph.D, probably not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example,

> Bachelor of Computer Science (Software Engineering/Systems Security)
>
> University of XX 2007-2009 (Dean's Scholar)

I think *Dean's Scholar* is optional. I added it in the second line only because you have it in your example and I have a feeling that you are proud of it..

Industry companies pay attention to skills and experience. Whether you were Dean's Scholar when you graduated is not that relevant. I personally would take it out from my resume because it would add too much unimportant information. I would save it for more important things such as my programming experience in my resume if I were you.

So, you have six items in your education section total 12 lines (about half page).

As I said in my comment, your academic CV would be a totally different story.

Comment: IF you only have a few (or no) years of work experience, the Dean's list might be worth mentioning; if the example degree was the first that roffster earned this is quite possible.  Once you've got a few years of experience, I agree that it's probably no longer worth mentioning.

Comment: @DanNeely I agree. That's why I still list it there. However, I feel that the way I list it looks somewhat awkward. Given that the OP has six items in Education, I'd rather omit that Dean's list to save the space. It's trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have no experience (internships count as experience), you should list your degree's in chronological order.

Do it on one line as so

> B.S. Of Computer Science - University of XYZ (GPA here if you want)

Leave off Dean's Scholar.  Once you get a grad degree, you should focus on what you did as a graduate student.  You wouldn't have been accepted to grad school without good grades.  Focus on achievements as a grad student.

Hiring managers (in industry) will likely be looking MUCH more at experience than anything else.

Answer (score -2):

I honestly don't think it is relevant to list Undergrad degrees when you have a master. I would just list the masters. The part about you pursuing a phd is quite important because it would tell a employer that you plan to pursue it and potentially limit your work schedule and/or work at different hours.